# Need help in figuring out how this code works

Tags: javascript

So there's this challenge on freeCodeCamp :

*Find the smallest common multiple of the provided parameters that can be evenly divided by both, as well as by all sequential numbers in the range between these parameters.*

*The range will be an array of two numbers that will not necessarily be in numerical order.*

*For example, if given 1 and 3, find the smallest common multiple of both 1 and 3 that is also evenly divisible by all numbers between 1 and 3. The answer here would be 6.*

There's a very short solution I found on the forum, but inspite of racking my brain for several days, I've not been able to figure out how it goes about it. Here's the code.

```
    function smallestCommons(arr) {

      var max = Math.max(arr[0], arr[1]);
      var min = Math.min(arr[0], arr[1]);
      var mltple = max;

      for(var i = max; i >= min; i--){
        if(mltple % i !== 0){
          mltple += max; 
          i = max;
        } 
      }

      return mltple;  
    }
```

Can someone explain just what's happening? The brevity of it is intriguing but would love to know what's up.

Comment: Please, read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253896/2988 to understand why "Explain this code to me" questions are off-topic, and what you can do to make it on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See inline comments:

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  // given: arr is an array containing two integers
  // they are accessed using their indexes

  // figure out which of the numbers is greater
  var max = Math.max(arr[0], arr[1]);

  // figure out which of the numbers is lesser
  var min = Math.min(arr[0], arr[1]);

  // declare the variable mltple which will hold the answer
  // it can't be less than the greater of the two numbers in arr
  // so set it to max
  var mltple = max;

  // start with the larger of the numbers in arr (i.e. max)
  // count down and run the following loop for each number 
  // until we reach min
  // i will keep track of the number as it counts down
  for (var i = max; i >= min; i--) {

    // check to see if there is a remainder when mltple
    // is divided by i
    // if there is, then mltple must not be 
    // the least common multiple
    if (mltple % i !== 0) {

      // as long as there's no remainder,
      // we increase mltple by max
      mltple += max;

      // set i to max and begin the countdown loop again
      i = max;
    }
    // if there is no remainder when dividing mltple by i
    // then i is decreased by 1 and the loop runs again
    // when i reaches a number less than min, the loop exits
    // and the function returns the value of mltple
  }

  return mltple;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the code takes a variable multple (initializes it to max) and checks if multple is multiple of all the values between max and min. If it is true it returns it. 
Else it increments max in multple (multple+=max) and repeats the steps starting from i=max again and checking all values from max to min. 
Hope this helps. Let me know if you still didnt understand.

Btw I think this code is finding a common multiple of all values that lie between max and min. as it loops through starting from max until min and it checks multple against all values.

Answer (score 0):

Since we are trying to find a common multiple, the lowest common multiple of 2 numbers could be (but not necessarily) the greater number of the two. So, thats where we start the test ie. starting from the greater number of the two.
Take the two numbers as 2 and 3. Multiples of 2 are 2,4,6,8.... and so on and those of 3 are 3,6,9,12.... and so on.
Here the common multiples could only be the multiples of the greater number ie 3. Thats why the variable mltple is incremented everytime by the greater number. Next we are looping through all the numbers which should divide the mltple as per the requirement. As soon as all the conditions are met, we return the answer.